# How to get two fields while creating session?

Tags: php, postgresql

In my login page I am using a phone number and password fields only to login, thereafter, I am creating and storing a session using the phone number.

Insted, I want to echo the **username** currently logged in to display the current user becasue in my case I am currently only able to display the **phone number** of the logged in user. How do I do that?

Here is my login script

```
<?php
     // Starting Session
    session_start();

    include "../script.php";

    $error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message

    if (isset($_POST['signin'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['signinphone']) || empty($_POST['signpassword'])) {



         $error = "Phone or Password is invalid";
    }
    else
    {
    // Define $username and $password
    $phone=$_POST['signinphone'];
    $password=$_POST['signpassword'];


    // To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose


        $phone = stripslashes($phone);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $phone = pg_escape_string($db, $phone); // Set email variable
        $password = pg_escape_string($db, $password); // Set hash variable

        $pass_crypted = password_hash($password);

    // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.

        $sql="SELECT usr_id, usr_email, usr_first_name, usr_last_name, 
              usr_encrypted_password,
                      usr_salt, usr_stos_id, usr_pers_id, usr_username, usr_updated_at,
                      usr_created_at, usr_enabled, usr_role_id, usr_jbrn_id, 
              usr_mobile_number,
                      stp_acc_id, usr_location, usr_mobile_imei, usr_type
                 FROM js_core.stp_users

                 where usr_mobile_number='$phone'

                 AND usr_encrypted_password='$password'";
        $result=pg_query($db, $sql);

        $rows = pg_num_rows($result);

        if ($rows == 1) {
              $_SESSION['phone']=$phone; // Initializing Session
              $_SESSION['username'] = pg_fetch_object($result)->usr_last_name;
              header("location: ../index.php");

              } else {
            //echo "0 results";

                echo "Try Again the credentials you entered don't much ours";

            }

        ; // Closing Connection

        }
        }


    ?>
```

and Here is my sample code where I want to display the username inplace of the phone

```
  <li>
      <?php

                    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

                      echo '<li><a href="#">'. $_SESSION["username"] . '</a></li>';
                      echo '<li>
                            <a href="config/logout.php" id="logout">Log Out</a></li>';
                    } else {
                    echo '<a class="signing" href="#login" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signIn">Login </a>';
                    }
      ?>
 </li>
```

Comment: assign a session array to the post array. Plus, you're not going live with this, I hope. MD5 isn't safe anymore.

Comment: @Fred-ii- How exactly do I do that?

Comment: You are getting all the user info from the query, so just save the bits you need to session. For example, after the line `if($rows ==1){` add: `$_SESSION['username'] = pg_fetch_object($result)->usr_username;`

Comment: As mentioned by @Fred-ii- md5 is no longer safe for passwords, and PDO with prepared statements a lot more reliable than manual escaping. I take it you are working on someone elses code

Comment: @Steve I have added the line and echoed the session in my html to display the username but still it displays the phone number.

Comment: Other comments aside, when you pass the password to a hashing function (preferably not md5), you'll clear any SQL injection anyway, so you should do as little to it before that as possible to ensure that the hash is consistent.  (provided you use a standard hashing function, e.g. `password_hash()`)

Comment: @Steve I have updated the code above.

Comment: @calcinai now have a look at the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

There is not one answer to your question.

I'm posting this because it contains an example of all the things that have been mentioned in the comments to your question.

Firstly, you'll notice that there is a new `$db` connection that uses the PDO.  This is the generally accepted way to handle DB connections and is relatively easy to install (if your php version doesn't have it) - there are plenty of examples on SO.  I'd assume you'd want this in your `script.php` since it's common.

I've also swapped out the password hashing function for the native `BCRYPT` [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.  When you sign the user up, you would then use it like so:

```
$encryped_password = password_hash($_POST['signpassword'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

This contains a uniquely salted password with the default cost.

Following that, you can fetch the user as you were, with the small adjustment to make it a prepared statement.  This provides SQL Injection protection and generally makes things cleaner.

You'll then see that after the row is fetched, you can compare the password with the `password_verify()` function.

Finally to your original issue - I've set the PDO mode to object, so you can access and assign as many properties as you need to in the same way.  Only the properties in the `SELECT` clause will be available in that object.

```
// Starting Session
session_start(); //I'd suggest this should also go in your script.php

$db = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost;user=myuser;password=mypass');

include "../script.php";

$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message

if (isset($_POST['signin'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['signinphone']) || empty($_POST['signpassword'])) {
        $error = "Phone or Password is invalid";
    }
    else
    {
        // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
        $sql = 'SELECT usr_id, usr_email, usr_first_name, usr_last_name, usr_encrypted_password
                          usr_stos_id, usr_pers_id, usr_username, usr_updated_at,
                          usr_created_at, usr_enabled, usr_role_id, usr_jbrn_id,
                          usr_mobile_number, stp_acc_id, usr_location, usr_mobile_imei,
                          usr_type
                     FROM js_core.stp_users
                     WHERE usr_mobile_number = :phone_number';

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(['phone_number' => $_POST['signinphone']]);

        if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            if(password_verify($_POST['signinpassword'], $row->usr_encrypted_password)) {
                $_SESSION['phone'] = $row->usr_mobile_number; // Initializing Session
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row->usr_username;

                header("location: ../index.php");
            } else {
                //valid user, invalid password
            }
        } else {
            //Invalid user
            echo "Try Again the credentials you entered don't much ours";
        }
    }
}
```

I've made the assumption that you're running at lease PHP 5.5 for the password_hash, but there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) if not.